# check number of times consecutive value appear based on a certain criteria

Tags: r

I want to find how many times 2/3/4/5/6 consecutive numbers  greater than a particular number appear in a vector. For e.g. for the following vector

```
x=c(1,1,3,4,9,1,9,1,5,4,5,2,1,1,4,6)
```

count the number of times two consecutive numbers are > 3 (4,9) & (4,6) = 2
three consecutive numbers > 3 (e.g. 5,4,5) = 1
and so on for 4,5,6 consecutive numbers

The following code only gives me how many times a value occur consecutively.

```
runs <- rle(x) 
with(runs, table(values, lengths))
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
f1 <- function(vec, val, n){
rl <- rle(vec >val)
sum(rl$lengths[rl$values]==n)
}

 f1(x, 3, 2)
 #[1] 2
 f1(x, 3, 3)
 #[1] 1
```

Or to do that all at once

```
sapply(2:6, function(y) {rl <- rle(x>y);sum(rl$lengths[rl$values]==2)})
# [1] 1 2 0 0 0
sapply(2:6, function(y) {rl <- rle(x>y);sum(rl$lengths[rl$values]==3)})
#[1] 2 1 0 0 0
sapply(2:6, function(y) {rl <- rle(x>y);sum(rl$lengths[rl$values]==4)})
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```